# Fourier Transform of the full Morlet wavelet

Tags: fourier-transform, wavelet

In 2014 someone asked here the Fourier transform of the Morlet wavelet; link below:

[Fourier Transform of Morlet wavelet Function?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/14323/fourier-transform-of-morlet-wavelet-function)

However, it was the approximated Morlet wavelet not written with the canonical Gaussian function.

Can somebody help to find the Fourier Transform of the full scaled Morlet wavelet below:

$$\psi_{\mu}(\tfrac{t}{\mu}) = \frac{1}{\mu} \times \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \, \sigma} \, e^{\frac{ -\left(\frac{t}{\mu} \right)^2}{2\sigma^2}} \big[e^{j\omega_c \frac{t}{\mu}}-e^{-\frac{1}{2} \omega_c^2}\big]$$

where $\omega_c = 2\pi f_c$ and $f_c$ is the centre or carrier frequency of the wavelet (the frequency to which the wavelet oscillates in the temporal domain). Also, $\mu$ is the scaling factor defined as $\mu = \frac{\omega_c}{\omega_{\mu}}$, where $\omega_{\mu}$ is the analysing frequency. Indeed, when $\omega_{\mu} = \omega_{c} \Rightarrow \mu = 1$ we have the mother Morlet wavelet.

In addition, the second term in the brackets is the correction term necessary to enforce zero mean to the Morlet wavelet.

I'd much appreciate a detailed step-by-step demonstration if possible to check where I'm getting stuck in my own demonstration. It could be done in a paper if quicker and a photo sent to me; I'll then publish here the full demonstration here.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Welcome to SE.DSP. You have more chance to get an answer if you first detail your own demonstration, so that we can help detect the weaker spots

Comment: Hi, I've tried several times but got stuck.

Comment: Please show your work and where exactly you are getting stuck. Thanks!

Comment: I've split the integral into two parts and try to take the Fourier of each separately for simplicity. I'm currently finishing writing up a paper and will show my work in a couple of days hopefully. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

if you wanna do this with ordinary frequency $f$ (rather than angular frequency $\omega$) youcan start with

$$ \mathscr{F}\Big\{ x(t) \Big\} \triangleq \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) \, e^{-j 2 \pi f t} \, dt $$

$$ \mathscr{F}\left\{ e^{-\pi t^2} \right\} = e^{-\pi f^2} $$

$$ \mathscr{F}\left\{ e^{-\pi \alpha t^2} \right\} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha}} e^{-\frac{\pi}{\alpha} f^2} \qquad \alpha > 0 $$

$$ \mathscr{F}\left\{ e^{-\pi \alpha (t-\tau)^2} \right\} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha}} e^{-\frac{\pi}{\alpha} f^2} e^{-j 2 \pi f \tau} $$

Comment: and [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/56574/stft-calculation-with-gaussian-window/56583#56583) has a general gaussian Fourier transform.

Comment: Hi Robert, thank you so much for your great help. I've downloaded your 2001 paper, and read the comments related to the general gaussian Fourier transform. I think the latter should answer my question. But, I'd like to come back to you, later on, to understand how the Fourier of the general gaussian is obtained; I'm curious about this indeed. Once again thank you very much,  and I hope to soon put the answer on this page. So great!!!!

Comment: sure, come back when you're ready.  i think the trick for computing the Fourier Transform of the gaussian might be in completing the square.