# Standard deviation of Morlet wavelet's Fourier transform

Tags: matlab, wavelet, gaussian

MATLAB has the complex Morlet Wavelet in the following form:

$$\psi(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi f_b}}e^{\frac{-t^2}{f_b}}e^{j2\pi f_ct}$$

I arrived at its Fourier transform as shown below (another arrived at the same: [Fourier Transform of Morlet wavelet Function?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/14323/fourier-transform-of-morlet-wavelet-function)).

$$X(f)=\mathcal F(x)(f)=e^{-\pi^2 f_b(f-f_c)^2}$$

I sought a relationship between $f_b$ and the standard deviation of the Gaussian form of $X(f)$. Is it right? Is there any citable published literature (book or journal article) arriving at this relationship?

Rearranging this into the familiar Gaussian form,
$$X(f) = e^{\frac{-(f-f_c)^2}{2\left({\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{2f_b} })}\right)^2}}$$

The standard deviation $(\sigma_f)$ of this frequency domain Gaussian is then,
$$\sigma_f = \frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{2f_b}}$$
Rearranging it,
$$f_b = \frac{1}{2{(\pi\sigma_f)}^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

I might have the ingredients to an answer [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/56574/stft-calculation-with-gaussian-window/56583#56583) and [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/56574/stft-calculation-with-gaussian-window/56642#56642) and [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3927319_Intraframe_time-scaling_of_nonstationary_sinusoids_within_the_phase_vocoder).